# Singlet gluon interaction

Tags: particle-physics

If a ninth singlet gluon existed (U(3) instead of SU(3)) it would propagate freely interacting strongly. My question is: only with hadrons or, perhaps, with leptons (I.e, electrons) as well?

Answer (score 1):

*If* there were a ninth gluon ...  The precise wording of your question predetermines the answer.  If the supernumerary gluon were the ninth generator of U(3), then it would couple to baryon number alone; but if it were the additional diagonal generator of a grand SU(4) broken to SU(3)xU(1), then it would couple to hypercharge.  There is a somewhat esoteric reason, connected with anomalies, to think that it would have to be the latter.  The renormalization group also has something to say:  Even if all gluons had equal couplings at the Planck scale, radiative corrections would weaken the U(1) gluon’s coupling at lower energies, while strengthening the SU(3) gluons’ coupling.